# Kotlinで漢字からかな変換の方法を教えて下さい！

Tags: java, kotlin

現在、Android studioでユーザの入力フォームを作っています。
その際、ユーザネームを漢字で入力してもらう予定なのですが、
その漢字をかな変換したいと思っています。

以下のようなクラスを作成しても、変換されませんでした。

```
class TextConverter(){
    companion object {
        fun convertKanjiToHiragana(kanji: String): String {
            // Unicode正規化を行い、カタカナと濁点・半濁点をひらがなに変換する
            val hiragana = Normalizer.normalize(kanji, Normalizer.Form.NFKC)
                .replace("[\\p{InKatakana}\\p{InHalfwidthAndFullwidthForms}]+".toRegex()) { matchResult ->
                    val katakana = matchResult.value
                    StringBuilder(katakana.length).apply {
                        for (i in katakana.indices) {
                            val c = katakana[i]
                            append(if (c >= '\u30A1' && c <= '\u30F6') c - 0x60 else c)
                        }
                    }.toString()
                }
            return hiragana
        }
    }
}
```

どうやったら解決できるでしょうか？ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: もう少し状況を正確に説明する必要があるように感じます。コード中のコメントには「カタカナ(中略)をひらがなに変換する」とありますので、期待通り動作したとしても質問タイトルにある「漢字からかな変換」が為されないのは当然のように思われます。